# Not able to setup e2e tests for nestjs with docker-compose for github actions

Tags: docker-compose, jestjs, nestjs, github-actions, e2e-testing

I have added [Dockerfile](https://github.com/SankethBK/test-jest/blob/master/Dockerfile) and [docker-compose](https://github.com/SankethBK/test-jest/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) file to standard Nestjs project that comes with `nest new <project-name>` to run e2e tests via `nest run test:e2e` command.  In actual application iave postgres and redis as dependencies, so i want to run e2e tests on github actions with docker-compose.

Repository: https://github.com/SankethBK/test-jest
Github actions: https://github.com/SankethBK/test-jest/actions/runs/7505978598/job/20436388789

Everything works fine when i run it locally via

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run backend-core npm run test:e2e
```

But in Github actions it fails with this error:

```
1s
Run docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml run backend-core npm run test:e2e
Creating network "test-jest_default" with the default driver
Creating test-jest_backend-core_run ... 
Creating test-jest_backend-core_run ... done

> test-jest@0.0.1 test:e2e
> jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json

● Validation Error:

  Module ts-jest in the transform option was not found.
         <rootDir> is: /app/test

  Configuration Documentation:
  https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration

1
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I am using node.js 16.17 locally, I am using pretty much same version in Github actions as well

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/6674 (check this comment https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/6674#issuecomment-415600375 on this thread)

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant but there are these ["EBADENGINE Unsupported engine"](https://github.com/SankethBK/test-jest/actions/runs/7506026949/job/20436537748#step:5:99) logs in your build step.

Comment: The workaround is already mentioned in that [comment](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/6674#issuecomment-415600375). Have you tried that?

Comment: It didn't work, got this error `
  Module <rootDir>/node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js in the transform option was not found.
         <rootDir> is: /app/test
`

Comment: I figured out a workaround by mentioning services in github actions rather than using docker compose

Comment: Good to hear that. You may self-answer this. Would be helpful for future readers if you added why it doesn't work `docker-compose` but works with GHA service containers. All the best!

Comment: Actually I couldn't figure out why it doesn't work with docker-compose, but i found its not necessary to use docker-compose while using github actions as it has built in support for launching multiple containers similar to docker-compose

Comment: Which way did you found?